# What would cause 'Unable to create temp dir "flash:/update"' when updating Cisco AP?

Tags: cisco, wireless, aironet, cisco-wireless

When trying to update an Aironet 1262 to a new firmware, I received this error:

```
ap#archive download-sw /overwrite scp://root@10.10.10.10/ap3g1-k9w8-tar.152-4.JB5.tar
Unable to create temp dir "flash:/update"
```

My first thought is that the flash was full. Which is odd since normally updating the firmware, I overwrite the old firmware. However, even `dir` resulted in an error:

```
ap#dir
%Error opening flash:/ (Invalid argument)
```

How do I resolve this issue without trying a reboot of the AP and risking it not booting due to a flash error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many Cisco devices include the `fsck` command to check the file system with. If you run this command on the flash, it will attempt to fix file system errors for you. These were my results:

```
ap#fsck flash:
Fsck operation may take a while. Continue? [confirm]
flashfs[3]: WARNING - Unable to allocate backup blocks.
Please free some space on the flash file system.
flashfs[3]: 202 files, 7 directories
flashfs[3]: 0 orphaned files, 0 orphaned directories
flashfs[3]: Total bytes: 31610880
flashfs[3]: Bytes used: 31610880
flashfs[3]: Bytes available: 0
flashfs[3]: flashfs fsck took 19 seconds.
Fsck of flash: complete
```

Well, this appears to have proved that the file system is full. But did it fix the issue with the flash system so I could look at the flash system to find files to delete? Yes:

```
ap#dir
Directory of flash:/

    2  -rwx          64   Mar 1 1993 00:03:30 +00:00  sensord_CSPRNG0
    3  -rwx    12257280   Mar 1 2002 00:44:20 +00:00  ap3g1-k9w7-tar.152-2.JB.tar
    4  -rwx        1864   Mar 1 1993 00:04:03 +00:00  backup.config
    5  -rwx      294235   Apr 3 2014 22:01:12 +00:00  ap_log_r1_0.log
    6  -rwx           0   Apr 4 2014 08:12:42 +00:00  env_vars.tmp
    7  -rwx        2072   Mar 1 1993 20:26:00 +00:00  private-multiple-fs
    8  drwx         832   Mar 1 2002 00:54:21 +00:00  ap3g1-k9w7-mx.152-2.JB
   11  -rwx        3567   Mar 1 1993 20:26:00 +00:00  private-config
   12  -rwx          64   Apr 3 2014 22:16:37 +00:00  sensord_CSPRNG1
   13  -rwx       25960   Mar 1 1993 01:05:43 +00:00  event.log
   14  -rwx           4  Feb 18 2014 21:02:33 +00:00  FOC16441UX9
   15  -rwx      158878   Mar 7 1993 20:49:30 +00:00  event.r1
   16  -rwx      294235   Apr 3 2014 22:01:17 +00:00  ap_log_r1_1.log
   17  -rwx      294235   Apr 3 2014 22:01:22 +00:00  ap_log_r1_2.log
   18  -rwx     6111232   Apr 3 2014 22:16:23 +00:00  r1.rcore
   19  -rwx           0   Apr 3 2014 22:16:27 +00:00  r1.rcore.info
   20  -rwx         217   Apr 3 2014 20:16:20 +00:00  env_vars

31610880 bytes total (0 bytes free)
ap#
```

You can see why the file system is full, someone copied a firmware tarball direct to the AP's flash instead of using the archive command to pull it remotely. Easy fix though, just delete the tarball:

```
ap#del flash:ap3g1-k9w7-tar.152-2.JB.tar
Delete filename [ap3g1-k9w7-tar.152-2.JB.tar]? 
Delete flash:/ap3g1-k9w7-tar.152-2.JB.tar? [confirm]
ap#dir
Directory of flash:/

    2  -rwx          64   Mar 1 1993 00:03:30 +00:00  sensord_CSPRNG0
    4  -rwx        1864   Mar 1 1993 00:04:03 +00:00  backup.config
    5  -rwx      294235   Apr 3 2014 22:01:12 +00:00  ap_log_r1_0.log
    6  -rwx           0   Apr 4 2014 08:12:42 +00:00  env_vars.tmp
    7  -rwx        2072   Mar 1 1993 20:26:00 +00:00  private-multiple-fs
    8  drwx         832   Mar 1 2002 00:54:21 +00:00  ap3g1-k9w7-mx.152-2.JB
   11  -rwx        3567   Mar 1 1993 20:26:00 +00:00  private-config
   12  -rwx          64   Apr 3 2014 22:16:37 +00:00  sensord_CSPRNG1
   13  -rwx       25960   Mar 1 1993 01:05:43 +00:00  event.log
   14  -rwx           4  Feb 18 2014 21:02:33 +00:00  FOC16441UX9
   15  -rwx      158878   Mar 7 1993 20:49:30 +00:00  event.r1
   16  -rwx      294235   Apr 3 2014 22:01:17 +00:00  ap_log_r1_1.log
   17  -rwx      294235   Apr 3 2014 22:01:22 +00:00  ap_log_r1_2.log
   18  -rwx     6111232   Apr 3 2014 22:16:23 +00:00  r1.rcore
   19  -rwx           0   Apr 3 2014 22:16:27 +00:00  r1.rcore.info
   20  -rwx         217   Apr 3 2014 20:16:20 +00:00  env_vars

31610880 bytes total (12257280 bytes free)
ap#
```

Ok, file system fixed. Free space created. Did all of this fix the original issue of updating the firmware? Yes:

```
ap#archive download-sw /overwrite scp://root@10.10.10.10/ap3g1-k9w8-tar.152-4.JB5.tar
examining image...
Password: 
 Sending file modes: C0644 10475520 ap3g1-k9w8-tar.152-4.JB5.tar

extracting info (286 bytes)
Image info:
    Version Suffix: k9w8-.152-4.JB5
    Image Name: ap3g1-k9w8-mx.152-4.JB5
    Version Directory: ap3g1-k9w8-mx.152-4.JB5
    Ios Image Size: 594432
    Total Image Size: 10465792
    Image Feature: WIRELESS LAN|LWAPP
    Image Family: AP3G1
    Wireless Switch Management Version: 7.6.100.0
Extracting files...!
```